# Area estimation using raster image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, area, tools

I have a map of trace gas (NO2) distribution over big cities and other anthropogenic objects. The purpose is to estimate the area of distribution. [image] I attached the sample image to illustrate what I do.

Is there some tool in ArcGIS to carry out such an operation?

I have just one multi-stage idea: exclude low values pixels---- convert new image into polygons----estimate the area of each polygon. Maybe there is some more elegant solution?

Comment: The answer depends on the projection you are using.  If it is not an equal area projection, then you may need to adjust for its area distortion, depending on your accuracy requirements.

Answer (score 2):

basically you could reclassify your image and directly read the pixel count in the raster attribute table. Multiplying count by pixel size would give you the area. As mentioned by @whuber, this assume that you are using an equal area projection (which should also be the case if you work with vectors).

Comment: Thank you for a good idea. But there is another one problem - I have no attribute table for my rasters. Is it possible to get it using conversion tools?

Comment: you can use "build raster attribute table", but as mentioned in my answer you will need to reclasify first, or make sure that your data is stored in integer values (float raster do not have raster attribute table)

Comment: This solution implicitly assumes an Equal Area projection has been used.  I think this is such an important assumption that it should explicitly be included in the answer.

Comment: I've tried to use the method above. Well, it's interesting to use another projection and compare results. Thank you!